# Acentuação se mostra ilegível na página

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, iso-8859-1

A minha página(Cabeçalho de uma table e um popup modal), em letras acentuadas ou caracteres da lingua portuguesa, estão vindo de forma ilegível. No head da página eu tenho essa declaração:

```
<head>
<title><%=Application("app")%></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../gen/modal/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../gen/modal/modal.crossbrowser.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\gen\css\css002.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\gen\css\css007.css"> <!--cadeia de pagamento -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="\gen\js\tabelafixa.js"></script><!--cadeia de pagamento -->

<script src="../../gen/js/cpaint2.inc.compressed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="\atb\asp\atb0037.js?<%=now()%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="\atc\asp\atc0006.js?<%=now()%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="\cal\asp\cal0087.js?<%=now()%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="\cal\asp\cal0088.js?<%=now()%>"></script>
<!--INICIO BARRA DE PROGRESSO-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../gen/js/waitbar.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\gen\css\progbar.css">
<!--FIM BARRA DE PROGRESSO-->
</head>
```

Na tag meta eu também fiz isso e não resolveu:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Já passei UTF para utf e mesmo assim nada.
Tenho uma página chamadora do popup e nela eu tenho os includes e o meta para caracteres. A grid(table) está na mesma página que chama o popup. veja a imagem do grid como está.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se trocar o `charset` pra `utf-8`, funciona?

Comment: Tive problema igual, tente isso:
Na chamada do arquivo script inclua o charset="ISO-8859-1"
<script type=... charset="ISO-8859-1">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9417123/2932525) o *charset* enviado pelo o cabeçalho HTTP `Content-type` tem precedência ao *charset* informado por meta-tag, possivelmente por isso alterar a tag meta não resolveu, verifique os cabeçalhos de resposta se existe informação de *charset*.

---

Complementando com um exemplo os error de *charset* ([fonte](http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Como_resolver_problemas_de_acentua%C3%A7%C3%B5es_em_seu_site)):

> "Canção" armazenado em UTF-8 e exibido como ISO-8859-1: CanÃ§Ã£o
>
> "Canção" armazenado em ISO-8859-1 e exibido como UTF-8: Can��o

Comment: Cara, tive algo parecido com o que você está postando. Vou dar uma verificada mais detalhada e se resolver ou não, posto.

Comment: @pnet Pode ser também que o arquivo com essa tabela HTML está em UTF-8, como seu código parece ASP, imagino que você esteja usando IIS, e o projeto esteja em ISO-8859-1, se esse for o caso, modificar o *charset* do arquivo com o notepad++ (ou outro editor) deve resolver

Comment: Cara, bom dia. Como eu disse, já usei ambos e nada. O que eu desconfio é o arquivo js(Temos um arquivo para executar os papups de forma Modal). Achoe que pode ser ele, pois toda vez que nós incluímos ele na página, acontece esse problema. Estou nesse momento abrindo ele para ver se vejo algo de interessante que possa alterar a página.

Answer (score 3):

Fiz um teste usando no header o meta que vc passou e o body apenas com "Teste çãáâõ". Com UTF-8 funcionou e com ISO-8859-1 falhou. Coloque em um arquivo teste.html apenas o seguinte:

```
<html>
<header>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</header>
<body>
      Teste çãáâõ
<script src="teste.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

e verá que funciona. Ao menos funcionou pra mim no Firefox. Então com certeza deve ser alguma outra coisa além da tag meta.
Procure remover todas as linhas de scripts, teste e vá colocando de uma por uma.
Acho bem possível que a resposta do @Sançao tenha relevância tbém.

Answer (score 1):

basta colocar a tag meta com o charset tipo utf-8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Se não resolver então terá que configurar no arquivo de configuração do servidor http ( apache, toncat etc. ) se precisar de ajuda para esses casos é só comentar abaixo que edito a resposta

Comment: Aqui usamos o IIS, mas veja o seguinte. Não dava "pau" antes. Após eu incluir umas chamadas do jquery-ui.min.js e um arquivo js nosso para exibir páginas modais, é que eu observei esse problema. Tipo, antes de alterar um formulário funcionava, ao incluir essas chamadas, fiz as alterações, sendo que as alterações é apenas renomear uma função de: AbrePesquisa para AbrePesquisaMultiBrowser e essa função está no arquivo js nosso, recém criado. Creio que alguma coisa está conflitando nesse arquivo. Antes era UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Pesquisando a internet consegui encontrar uma tabela de códigos que substituem os acentos, segue abaixo:

`á = \u00e1
à = \u00e0
â = \u00e2
ã = \u00e3
ä = \u00e4
Á = \u00c1
À = \u00c0
Â = \u00c2
Ã = \u00c3
Ä = \u00c4
é = \u00e9
è = \u00e8
ê = \u00ea
ê = \u00ea
É = \u00c9
È = \u00c8
Ê = \u00ca
Ë = \u00cb
í = \u00ed
ì = \u00ec
î = \u00ee
ï = \u00ef
Í = \u00cd
Ì = \u00cc
Î = \u00ce
Ï = \u00cf
ó = \u00f3
ò = \u00f2
ô = \u00f4
õ = \u00f5
ö = \u00f6
Ó = \u00d3
Ò = \u00d2
Ô = \u00d4
Õ = \u00d5
Ö = \u00d6
ú = \u00fa
ù = \u00f9
û = \u00fb
ü = \u00fc
Ú = \u00da
Ù = \u00d9
Û = \u00db
ç = \u00e7
Ç = \u00c7
ñ = \u00f1
Ñ = \u00d1
& = \u0026
' = \u0027`

Exemplo:

`alert("O campo nome é de preechimento obrigatório ");`

Substituindo ficaria:

```
alert("O campo nome \u00e9 de preenchimento obrigat\u00f3rio");
```

Comment: Tiago, do que necessariamente você precisa?