# Problemas com codificação PHP em UTF-8

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Nenhuma das soluções sugeridas em diversos foruns, websites e afins funcionou. Realizei diversos testes e nenhum deles funcionou e por isso vim aqui.

O website onde ocorre o erro é este:
http://simuladoconcursosbrasil.com.br/

Não foi desenvolvido por mim, um cliente meu solicitou que eu corrigisse este problema para ele.

Todos os caracteres especiais são substituidos sempre por Ã . Tentei alterar a codificação para `ISO` e o erro se mantinha, tentei alterar a codificação no banco de dados, forçar `UTF-8` no `header`, botar o `javascript` para interpretar como `UTF-8` e nada disso funcionou.

A conexão no banco de dados está da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php
$bd_host = "localhost";
$bd_user = "simulado_bd"; // Usuário do Banco de Dados
$bd_pass = "********"; // Senha do Bando de Dados
$bd_bd = "simulado_bd"; // Nome do Banco de Dados
$conectar = mysql_connect($bd_host, $bd_user, $bd_pass) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($bd_bd, $conectar);
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

Comment: O que foi sugerido? qual é o encode do arquivo? da base?

Comment: Já tentou usar a tag <meta charset="UTF-8"> do HTML5? Não custa tentar :)

Comment: Como que esta a sua classe de conexão ao banco de dados?

Comment: perguntas respondidas relacionadas: [Acentuação se mostra ilegível na página](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82314/13561) e [Gravar dados MYSQL no formato pt-br / UTF8](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/92715/13561)

Comment: leitura recomendada: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4675/13561)

Comment: Arquivos Encodados em UTF-8, sem BOM, banco de dados em UTF-8 general ci

Comment: Sanção, como eu citei acima, não foi programado por mim, eu não utilizo funções tipo mysql_ a muito tempo.

Comment: Até agora nenhuma das dicas resolveu. Os dados no banco estão em UTF-8, mas não são lidos como deveriam.

Comment: @RaphaelCordeiro, tente adicionar o charset no header HTTP com `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: @Sanção tentei usar sua sugestão e o erro se manteve.

Comment: Olhando o fonte da página, me parece que foram feitas tentativas diversas de se arrumar os dados, incluindo "procurar e substituir" manualmente. Provavelmente é o caso de revisar a base de dados diretamente, pra depois consertar o PHP. Me parece inclusive ter entities misturadas com caracteres errados, e até duplo encode.

Comment: Raphael, se estiver relacionado somente a conteúdos vindos da base, precisa ver como foi gravado na base, será que não vale fazer um teste de inclusão de qualquer texto acentuado e em seguida lê-lo utilizando utf8_encode / utf8_decode?

Comment: E como eu faria isso, @ThyagoThySofT ? Bacco, eu tentei fazer uma substituição para corrigir sim, utilizando os códigos referentes aos caracteres acentuados, mas não funcionou, como pode reparar.

Comment: @RaphaelCordeiro a primeira coisa seria arrumar a base de dados então, nem que seja manualmente. Se ficar tentando arrumar pelo PHP, pode acontecer de aparentemente ter resolvido, mas você acabar criando ou escondendo um problema maior. Uma vez tendo certeza que o DB está correto, você pode tentar resolver o PHP. PS: Lembre-se de antes de mais nada, restaurar o backup do DB de antes das tentativas, para não complicar demais.

Comment: Uma coisa parece certa, são dois erros de codificação, o menu apresenta um tipo de erro de caracteres símbolos, já as perguntas e respostas que acredito que sejam do DB parece ser outro erro de codificação.

Comment: Os que tenho necessidade de resolver são apenas os que são puxados do banco de dados, o outro problema na codificação eu consigo resolver. Vou restaurar o backup do banco de dados do script, da forma que ele veio (e funcionava em outro servidor).

Comment: Se puder fazer um teste.... No formulario de inclusão para o BD, envie os campos assim: `htmlspecialchars($_POST['blablabla'], NULL, 'UTF-8')` consegue ver como está? Pelo menos terá certeza de um novo conteúdo incluido em utf-8.

Comment: Leia o dado vindo do BD assim: `utf8_encode($resultado)` estes testes é para rastrearmos, vamos achar o problema xD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Já tive o mesmo problema. Consegui resolver desta forma:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

Coloque todas as linhas após sua conexão, provavelmente funcionará!

Comment: Não funcionou :/

Comment: Você tem acesso ao arquivo php.ini no servidor? Se sim, verifique se o `default charset` está definido como UTF-8

Answer (score 3):

Verifique se o arquivo está convertido para `UTF-8 without BOM / UTF-8 sem BOM`.
Verifique se a base do MySQL está como `UTF_8`.

Se ambos estiverem corretos, faça o seguinte com suas páginas
no php

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

e no html

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: Não funcionou mesmo assim. Tipo, percebi que quando eu edito as perguntas e respostas, para de aparecer "Ã" no lugar dos carácteres acentuados e começa a aparecer "?"

Comment: O Ã que aparece é diferente, pois é um caractere especial gerado pela tentativa de converter o char... Você verificou se o arquivo seu de conexão, o arquivo que trabalha os dados e o banco de dados estão como `utf8 without BOM`? E verifica o seu navegador também se está com o encoding correto

Answer (score 3):

Talvez ajude alguém, eu estava com problemas no AJAX.

Eu estava usando no php:

```
*header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');*
```

Mudei para:

```
*header('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');*
```

Comment: o correto seria este `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`, você deve está utilizando arquivo com **BOM**

Comment: Achei que estava @WillBB, mas não, mudei o formato e agora está funcionando normal.